# set output location for pdftk sample.pdf burst

Tags: php, pdftk

I've a question, I am using tdftk to split pages of a pdf file from php.
using following command

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("pdftk ").escapeshellarg("/var/www/card/card.pdf")." ".escapeshellcmd(" burst");
$result = passthru($command);
```

it's working very well, and splitting the pages into files.

now my question is can i set the output location where burst files should be store.

by default it is placing the the files at site web root, where as I want the files at /var/www/card/pages/ directory.

is there any way to do this in PDFTK?

Please please help me with this...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wanted to do the exact same thing : you can specify the output directory and the name format with the "output" parameter of pdftk.
ex :

```
pdftk your_file.pdf burst output your_directory/page_%02d.pdf
```

See the pdftk doc for more informations :

http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-burst

Hope this helps,
Vincent